# Restore database with full backup to exact date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-restore

I'm trying restore a SQL Server 2008 R2 database to the date `01/07/2013` from a full backup dated `11/04/2014`. Is this restore possible?

Thanks

Comment: Voting to move this to [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: no. Simplifying a bit, backups are a snapshot to a point in time. If they worked the way you seem to want them to work, they'd be unbounded in space as they'd have to keep track of all previous state back to the inception of the database.